# How to populate Kendo grid with an angular $http GET call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, promise, angular-kendo

I'm having trouble binding a Kendo grid to an angular service call. I have an angular `$http` service that has a `getData()` method which looks like this:

```
'use-strict';

payrollApp.factory('dataService', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        getData: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/apihome/',
           }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.reject(status);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },
    };
});
```

I then set the grids `DataSource` in my controller as follows:

```
'use-strict';
payrollApp.controller('KendoDataGridController', function KendoDataGridController($scope, dataService) {

    var companiesList = dataService.getCompanies();
    companiesList.then(function(companies) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(companies, undefined, 2));
        $scope.companies = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: companies,
            pageSize: 10
        });
    }, function(status) {
        window.alert(status);
        console.log(status);
    });
}
);
```

but my grid is not populating. When I set the DataSource's data manually (hard-coded JSON array) it works fine but not when I'm getting the data in my service call, the JSON array being returned by my service is also a valid JSON array (exactly the same as the one I hard coded). Anybody has an idea? I have a feeling this is a promise issue, but even then I'm setting my `$scope's` `companies` property when the promise is resolved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I managed to fix it, there's 2 ways (quite possibly more) of doing this:

**1.** One is to directly give your kendo grid's datasource the adrress of the Api controller:

```
$scope.companies = new kendo.data.DataSource({
               transport: {
               read: {
                      url: '/api/apihome',
                      dataType: 'json'
                     },
               },
               pageSize: 10  
});
```

There's a full explanation [here](http://ernpac.net/?p=403). But I don't like doing this because I'd rather not hard code API controller addresses in my controller, I prefer to have a service or something return me the data and then pass that on to my grid (Imagine for example wanting to add a token in the `$http` request headers). So after some messing around I got a way of hooking up the grid with my original approach:

**2.** We can just hook up the read function of the grid to another function in our service or whatever, which can be any method returning a promise, i.e. a `$http` call:

```
dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: function (options) {//options holds the grids current page and filter settings
                    $scope.getCompanies(options.data).then(function (data) {
                        options.success(data);
                        $scope.data = data.data;//keep a local copy of the data on the scope if you want
                        console.log(data);
                    });
                },
                parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                    return JSON.stringify(data);
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "data",
                total: "total",
            },
            pageSize: 25,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true
        },
```

**EDIT**

Regarding how to add items that are already available to the grid, and how to have subsequent requests to the server to get new data, this is how I've gone about doing this:

The grid has an `autoBind` property, setting that to false prevents the grid automatically calling the server when the view is loaded. So to add items manually I set this to false, and then add rows to the grid via the `dataSource.add()` method. After that calling `dataSource.read()` will retrieve more data from the server:

```
    $scope.companiesGridOptions = {
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: function (options) {
                    var config = {
                        method: "GET",
                        url: "/api/companies/GetCompanies"
                    };
                    $http(config).success(function (data) {
                        angular.forEach(data, function(d) {
                            $scope.companiesGridOptions.dataSource.add(d);
                        });

                    });
                }
            },....
```

Adding items manually to the grid:
   `$scope.companiesGridOptions.dataSource.data([{id:1,title:"..."}, {id:2,title:"..."}]);`

Calling `dataSource.read()` forces a server call to retrieve data:
   `$scope.companiesGridOptions.dataSource.read();`

Comment: How would you handle this if the data was already preloaded by the service when you resolved the route, yet you wanted all subsequent kendo data requests to get new data?

Comment: regarding _Imagine for example wanting to add a token in the $http request headers_ - you can use `beforeSend` as demostrated [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-set-authorization-header-for-transport-read)

Comment: @jajdoo Why write that extra code if you're already using an angular `$http` interceptor to add tokens? Moving the server call to a service provides you with more interception points.

Comment: i wholeheartedly agree, but my comment was more about the _its impossible_ part, as this may suggest it is ACTUALLY impossible to do so (should have added that part in the comment's quote).

Comment: @jajdoo Thanks for the heads up, will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try refreshing your grid once you populate new data:

```
your_grid.refresh();
```