# Kendo ListView is not showing/binding data

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui

I have Kendo UI ListView like following:

```
  <div ng-controller="patientSearchCtrl">
    <div kendo-list-view id="listView" k-data-source="source">
        <div class="product" k-template>
            <h3>{{ dataItem.First_Name }}</h3>
            <p>{{ dataItem.Last_Name }}</p> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div kendo-pager k-data-source="source"></div>
</div>
```

And following AngularJS code:

```
    angular.module("alertApp", ["kendo.directives"])
        .controller("patientSearchCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
            var product;
            $http.get('http://localhost:1242/Api/PatientSearch?firstName=Bar&lastName=wells&pageIndex=0&pageSize=10&sortingOrder=FIRST_NAME').
              success(function (info, status, headers, config) {                     
                  product = info[0]["Table"];
                  console.log(product); 
              }).
              error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  console.log('Error: ' + data);
              });
            $scope.source = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: product,
                pageSize: 1
            });
        });
```

console.log(product); is logging data. In Chrome it looks like:

```
[Object]
      0: Object
              DOB: "07-29-1969"
              First_Name: "Barbara"
              Last_Name: "Wells"
              PatientKey: 3
              RowIndex: 1
```

What is wrong I'm doing here?

Comment: I'm not sure how kendo list view works, but try to assign an empty array to 'product' variable, then push the data to that array in $http success call back.

Comment: check out this thread_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904048/how-to-populate-kendo-grid-with-an-angular-http-get-call It describes how to populate the grid with angularjs $http get.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$scope.source = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: product,
                pageSize: 1
            });
```

to

```
$scope.source = {
                data: product,
                pageSize: 1
            };
```

or

```
$scope.source = product;
```

---

To provide complete options. Use below code

```
<div kendo-list-view k-options="source "></div>

    $scope.source = {
              dataSource: products,
              template: "<div>#:First_Name#</div>"
          };
```